# BAT script to paste text

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have Windows and keyboard without the letter "L". 
I also have an application that allows me to run other programs with keyboard shortcut. Is it possible to write a batch file that will past the missing letter?

I want to run bat file by shortcurt, that will past letter, but I can't write that script. Can you help me?

Comment: just out of curiosity: how about getting a functional keyboard (for little money or maybe one of your friends has a spare one)?

Comment: @Stephan great idea!:) Sometimes I dont have second keyboard and I need write some quick mail on laptop. It's just workaround for hard times.

Comment: Press [ALT] while typing 076 to get an uppercase L resp. 108 for a lowercase one.

Comment: easiest way is [remap some unused key (like scroll lock, pause, menu, F8...) to L key](http://superuser.com/q/36920/241386)

Comment: @LotPings many new laptops don't have numpad to type alt codes. In those cases you'll have to use the virtual onscreen keyboard/copy-paste/remap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command line will copy the letter `L` to the clipboard

```
@set /P "_=L"<NUL|clip
```

Put the line into a batch, but choose a name without an L :-)